# Cannot preview in this file - Failed to get the location of the sandbox container for [AppName].app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just updated to macOS Big Sur. I created a new xcode product and opened up the contentview editor. I want to get the live previews going, but I keep getting the error "Cannot preview in this file - Failed to get the location of the sandbox container for [AppName].app". I have absolutely no clue what is going on. The only code written is the default code provided when you make a new xcode swiftUI project.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I just updated my version of xcode.